# Child of CObject in Copy Constructor Initializer List

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list

I've been tasked with porting some legacy code, and in doing so I'd like to follow best practices as much as possible, since my predecessor regrettably did not. Below is a basic framework of the issue I've run into:

```cpp
class Foo : public CPropertyPage
{
   // Constructor
   Foo() : CPropertyPage(Foo::ID)
   {
      pBar = new Bar();
      // init other things
   }

   // Copy Constructor
   Foo(const Foo& other) : CPropertPage(other) // C2248 compiler error
   {
      pBar = new Bar(*other.pBar);
      // copy other things
   }
}
```

Since I've read that it's best practice to write a copy constructor for a class when `new` is used in the constructor, that's what I'm trying to do. What I want to do, is include `CPropertyPage`'s copy constructor in `Foo`'s copy constructor initializer list, but this is not allowed, since `CPropertyPage` is a child of the MFC class `CObject`, whose copy constructor is private. If I try the constructor used in `Foo`'s constructor initializer list, it compiles, but I'm not sure if this achieves the same end as `CPropertyPage`'s copy constructor (Disclaimer: I'm quite new to copy constructors and initializer lists).

So, how can I properly write `Foo`'s copy constructor? Is my approach fundamentally flawed in some way?

EDIT: Attempt at syntax fixes, identified `CObject` as MFC class

Comment: `public class Foo`? That's not C++. And I doubt any language similar to C++ would need the scoping operator (`Foo::Foo`) inside the class definition.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would hazard a guess he copy / pasted from a CPP file, and then made it inline to be nice to our eyes. In either case, you can easily understand what he's asking about.

Comment: @ThePhD Basically, yes. The syntax isn't perfect, but I don't think that gets in the way of what I'm asking

Comment: No it's not necessarily the best practice. *If* copying is possible *then* you have to make sure it's done right, which *may* require writing a copy ctor. As a rule, most polymorphic classes just need copying disabled entirely.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, didn't know that. Perhaps the best solution would be to change pBar from a pointer to just an object? The only reason I'm implementing the copy constructor is because of the pointer needing a deep copy

Comment: Changing a member from a pointer to an object may or may not be a good idea, no general recipes here. It is advisable to disable copying anyway.

Comment: If you base class isn't copyable, your derived type probably shouldn't be, either. Lots of things cant/shouldnt be modifiable.

Comment: I should have clarified that `CObject` referred to the MFC class. I found an MSDN page addressing this issue. I'll clarify my question and post the link as answer. Thanks for all your advise nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an MSDN link pertaining to this issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccb3dh5c.aspx

Turns out my static analysis tool was being a little overzealous in checking for base classes in initializer lists.

Comment: clarifying this: No action needs to be taken , since `CPropertyPage` has copying disabled, this will disable copying for any derived classes unless you do actually provide a copy constructor.